# Jenkins input Parameter validation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins pipeline script to accept Docker Image Tag as arguments.  My tag format is like this `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`

During input how can I enforce this rules? Only accept numbers and dot (four numbers and three dots)

Here is the code I have.

```
  script {
        def userInput = input(id: 'userInput', message: 'Deploy Docker Image?',
                parameters: [[$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: '', description: 'Docker Image TAG ( eg. 1.5.23.67)', name: 'imageTag']])            
        imageTag = userInput                                    
        println(imageTag)

    }
```

Also `TextParameterDefinition` display multi line text area. Is there a way to display one line input filed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use [find operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator). It works in Pipelines DSL.

```
if (imageTag =~ '[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+') {
      doSomething()
}
```

And you can use [String](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Parametrized-pipelines) parameter instead of `TextParameterDefinition`

Comment: Thanks @fch Is there way to restrict during the inpurt itself.

Comment: Maybe replace all `\n`